# Logarithmic decreasing vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

is it possible to create a logarithmic decreasing vector in matlab? Trying to reverse the following

`x = logspace(log10(1), log10(3), 8)`

which creates a logarithmic spaced vector

```
x =

    1.0000    1.1699    1.3687    1.6013    1.8734    2.1918    2.5643    3.0000
```

Thank's for any advice.

Comment: What's wrong with `x = logspace(log10(2), log10(1), 8)`?

Comment: Reversing is done with `flip`.

Comment: ```x = logspace(log10(3),log10(1),8)

x =

    3.0000    2.5643    2.1918    1.8734    1.6013    1.3687    1.1699    1.0000```

Comment: The difference x(2) - x(1) is supposed to be the biggest

Comment: And x(1) must be the smallest number in x.

Comment: you mean like `log10(linspace(1,1000,8))` ? literally a log?

Comment: "x(1) must be the smallest number in x" -- Then it's not decreasing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a log?

```
log10(linspace(1,1000,8))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. x = logspace(log10(3), log10(1), 8)
2. x = logspace(log10(1), log10(3), 8); x1 = x(end:-1:1);x2 = fliplr(x);x3 = flip(x);